# Automating event handler remove when clearing dom node children

Tags: javascript, event-handling, introspection, nodes, removechild

Is there a way to introspect a dom node to see if there are event handlers attached, so you can effectively write a safe function to clear out the dom nodes without worrying about memory leaks left by event handlers? I was hoping to do this in a generic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see it might not be possible, here is a quote from mozilla site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Memory_issues

> Memory issues
>
> document.addEventListener("load",
>   function(event) { obj.func(event); },
>   false);
>
> Calling addEventListener to an
>   anonymous function creates a new
>   listener each time. Calling
>   removeEventListener to an anonymous
>   function has no effect. An anonymous
>   function creates a unique object each
>   time is is called, it is not a
>   reference to an existing object though
>   it may call one. When adding an event
>   listener in this manner be sure it is
>   added only once, it is permanent (can
>   not be removed) until the object it
>   was added to is destroyed.

if the listener is not anonymous you could do it. Here is a piece of code from YUI library Event:

```
        /**
         * Returns all listeners attached to the given element via addListener.
         * Optionally, you can specify a specific type of event to return.
         * @method getListeners
         * @param el {HTMLElement|string} the element or element id to inspect 
         * @param sType {string} optional type of listener to return. If
         * left out, all listeners will be returned
         * @return {Object} the listener. Contains the following fields:
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;type:   (string)   the type of event
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;fn:     (function) the callback supplied to addListener
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;obj:    (object)   the custom object supplied to addListener
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;adjust: (boolean|object)  whether or not to adjust the default context
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;scope: (boolean)  the derived context based on the adjust parameter
         * &nbsp;&nbsp;index:  (int)      its position in the Event util listener cache
         * @static
         */           
        getListeners: function(el, sType) {
            var results=[], searchLists;
            if (!sType) {
                searchLists = [listeners, unloadListeners];
            } else if (sType === "unload") {
                searchLists = [unloadListeners];
            } else {
                sType = this._getType(sType);
                searchLists = [listeners];
            }

            var oEl = (YAHOO.lang.isString(el)) ? this.getEl(el) : el;

            for (var j=0;j<searchLists.length; j=j+1) {
                var searchList = searchLists[j];
                if (searchList) {
                    for (var i=0,len=searchList.length; i<len ; ++i) {
                        var l = searchList[i];
                        if ( l  && l[this.EL] === oEl && 
                                (!sType || sType === l[this.TYPE]) ) {
                            results.push({
                                type:   l[this.TYPE],
                                fn:     l[this.FN],
                                obj:    l[this.OBJ],
                                adjust: l[this.OVERRIDE],
                                scope:  l[this.ADJ_SCOPE],
                                index:  i
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return (results.length) ? results : null;
        },
```

you can read more here: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/

Comment: Cheers. The YDN link at bottom made more sense of this. I'm guessing you have to use the YUI namespaced addEventListener and I assume this keeps track of the listeners by augmenting the nodes with a collection of listeners.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Simple event handlers assigned by property like `el.onclick = ...` can be effectively removed, but there is no list of handlers added via `attachEvent()` in *IE*. [Memory leaks](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html) are not much of a concern in other browsers.

```
/**
* The purge function takes a reference to a DOM element as an argument. 
* It loops through the element's attributes. If it finds any functions, 
* it nulls them out. This breaks the cycle, allowing memory to be reclaimed. 
* It will also look at all of the element's descendent elements, and clear 
* out all of their cycles as well.
*  - http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html
*/
function purge(d) {
    var a = d.attributes, i, l, n;
    if (a) {
        l = a.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            n = a[i].name;
            if (typeof d[n] === 'function') {
                d[n] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    a = d.childNodes;
    if (a) {
        l = a.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            purge(d.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to handle both cases and you manage all event handlers in your page you can **wrap `addEvent`** functionality in your own function, and delete them when an element is to be removed.

Comment: I had that sneaky suspicion there was no way to get to a list of attached handlers from using Firebug and looking at the properties on DOM nodes. The attributes approach is a good one if the page was coded in such a way, buy I tend to follow Nick Zakas's advice on this and avoid inlining event handlers with attributes.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I never suggested using attributes as event handlers. In fact the last sentence is the essence of my answer. **If** you control all the events on the page, you can **wrap** event handling very easily, and so removing event handlers from a given node shouldn't be a problem. By wrapping I mean something like: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/, I think my answer is pretty much complete for what is being asked here.